# Is memcmp guaranteed to compare bytes in order?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say that I have a pointer to a null-terminated string, `pString`. Let's say that I want to use `memcmp` to compare it to another string, for example:

```c
bool eq = memcmp(pString, "test", sizeof("test")) == 0;
```

`pString` could, in turn, be located at the end of a virtual page, and the next page can be unallocated. For example:

```c
char c1 = pString[0]; // 'x'
char c2 = pString[1]; // '\0'
char c3 = pString[2]; // ACCESS VIOLATION
```

In this case, if `memcmp` doesn't compare the bytes in order, the program may crash. My question is, is it guaranteed to do the comparison in order?

**Edit:** I know that `strcmp` exists. The example was just to clarify the question. For the actual question, please read the title. Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't have any sense: `memcmp` doesn't stop on zero byte.

Comment: The `memcmp` function have no knowledge about that pointers you pass to it. It relies on you passing a length argument that doesn't go out of bounds of either the arrays that the pointers might point to.

Comment: If you want to compare null-terminated strings use `strcmp` instead. Which I would not recommend in a C++ program where you have `std::string`.

Comment: And please note that C and C++ are two very different languages, and even things like `memcmp` and out of bounds behavior are worded differently in the respective specifications.

Comment: @273K If all bytes are compared individually in order, it would stop at the first byte that does not match. So it would stop at the zero byte because the other string does not have a zero byte.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine an implementation of `memcmp()` that doesn't read the bytes of each string in order, since the value returned by `memcmp()` depends strictly on the first pair-of-bytes in the strings that differs.

Comment: Btw `sizeof("test")` would count `\0` in the literal

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Think of vectorization (AVX, etc).

Comment: The spec of `memcmp` is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp. Period. No guarantee whatsoever. But the bahaviour of the function is described clearly.

Comment: @VLL, that is not true, memcpm can compare blocks and then specify a byte in unequal blocks.

Comment: Even if `memcmp` compares bytes in order it would most probably request them from memory in blocks of 8 or 4  bytes and then do comparison within a register: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memcmp.c#L74

Comment: @273K I said "If all bytes are compared individually in order" - that is what the question is about. If you know the answer to the question, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @VLL ok `memcmp("t", "t\0\0", 4)`..

Comment: You should ask the question you need answered. The question you need answered is "Will `memcmp` access memory beyond the first difference between the two arrays?" The answer is "possibly" due to vectorization.

Comment: No, you cannot make assumptions about the language implementation which are not given by the standard. The problem here is that you call `memcmp` with a size that is too large. You need to do `memcmp(pString, "test", min(N, sizeof("test"));` where `N` is the maximal accessible size of `pString`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this is the wrong question. `memcmp` can compare characters in whatever order it wants, if it returns the right answer at the end. (E.g. it could compare them in batches of 8, reinterpreting the string as `long long`s, etc.)

The right question is whether you're allowed to pass less bytes to it than specified by the last parameter, if the first different byte is before that position.

This causes undefined behavior.

C++ doesn't describe `memcmp`, and instead refers to the C standard. Which says (C23 draft N3096, 7.26.4.1 "The memcmp function"):

> The `memcmp` function compares the first `n` characters of the object pointed to by `s1` to the first `n` characters of the object pointed to by `s2`

Your object doesn't have "first `n` characters", since it hass less characters in total, hence this is UB.

There's also 7.1.4 "Use of library functions" /1, which says:

> If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer passed to the function shall
> have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if
> the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are valid.

While `memcmp` itself doesn't say it accepts an array, there is 7.26.1 "String function conventions" /1:

> useful for manipulating arrays of character type and other objects treated as arrays of character type.

So I believe the quote about arrays applies to `memcmp` too.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about correcting my question, that was my intention. Also, found this interesting blog post on the topic: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101014-00/?p=12533

Answer (score 12):

```
 int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

`memcmp` is not allowed read memory outside of the regions `[s1, s1+n)` and `[s2, s2+n)`, but it is allowed to read every single byte within these regions, even if the difference is found early. The order in which the comparison is done doesn't matter as long as the result is what it should be.

So it is not legal to call `memcmp("foo", "bar", 10)`.

Comment: *`memcmp` is not allowed read memory outside of the regions...*  I'd  say that `memcmp()` is not allowed to act *as if* it read memory outside the  bounds passed. 
  I could easily imagine an optimized implementation that uses system-specific knowledge of memory alignment and page size details to do things such as read aligned 8-byte chunks from 4k pages of memory without having to limit itself to the boundaries of the memory passed to the `memcmp()` function, for example. Thus `memcmp("foo", "foo", 10);` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The "as if" disclaimer is always in effect.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such guarantee in the C standard.

Here's a snippet of code that I suggest illustrates the problem more clearly:

```
char left[2]  = { 'x', '\0' };
char right[5] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };
memcmp(left, right, sizeof right);
```

You asked about the order in which the byte values are checked, but the relevant question is whether `memcmp` can access memory past the end of `left`.

The obvious implementation of `memcmp` scans from the beginning of both objects and stops when it encounters a mismatch. In such an implementation, there's no problem. But the standard makes no such guarantee. It says that:

> The **`memcmp`** function compares the first **`n`** characters of the object pointed to by **`s1`** to the first **`n`** characters of the object pointed to by **`s2`**.

Answer (score -1):

*This answer is for C.*

> Is memcmp guaranteed to compare bytes in order?

The C standard doesn't directly state that `memcmp` has to compare characters in a particular order. However, I think this part (from draft N1570 7.24.4) implicit says that the compare will happen "in order"

> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions memcmp, strcmp,
> and strncmp is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of **the first
> pair of characters** (both interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
> compared.

This tells us that any implementation of `memcmp` must find the **first** characters that doesn't match which implies that the implementation will start at offset zero and increase the offset until the characters differ..

In principle an implementation could start at offset `n-1` and go all the way to offset zero before being able to return but that would be a rather surprising implementation.

A less surprising implementation would be to do comparison in larger blocks, e.g. 4 or 8 bytes, and then do "byte-by-byte" compare to find the return value when two larger blocks differs.

Conclusion: Even if the standard doesn't explicit state an order, the requirements for the return value calculation strongly imply that the compare will be "in order" starting from offset zero.

Further, it is your responsibility to make sure that the two memory areas has a size at least as big as the passed "size" argument. In other words: Access violation won't happen if `memcmp` is used correctly.

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't follow. The implementation may compare in parts larger than bytes, and only when it detects a difference look at the individual bytes.

Comment: I just added that. In any case that will still be "in order" for any sane implementation.

Comment: The question asks if it can read bytes beyond the first difference, which it seems gcc does.

Comment: @Caleth The question asks about order. Anyway... yes, an implementation is allowed to read any byte as long as it's in the block size given by the last parameter.

Comment: Efficient versions of this function will probably compare words and not bytes for aligned data buffers.